# Drools does not see the rules and returns null as a result

Tags: drools

I have such code:

```
StatefulKnowledgeSession kSession = getKnowledgeBase().newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
this.insertFactsToWorkingMemory(inputCollection, kSession);
kSession.fireAllRules(new NotificationRuleNameFilter(name));
```

What `insertFactsToWorkingMemory` does is it takes object attributes and simply does `WorkingMemory.insert(fact)`.

The rules are stored in `.drl` file and looks like:

```
rule "USER.PASSWORD_RENEW"
when
    $config : UserSettings ( )
    eval( true )
then
    DroolsNotificationResult fact0 = new DroolsNotificationResult();
    fact0.setBusinessRulePassed( true );
    insert(fact0 );
end
```

The name of the rule and name passed in `NotificationRuleNameFilter(name)` match perfectly. Any clues?

Comment: How are you building your `KieBase`? Are you inserting a `UserSettings` in your session? What happens if you don't use a filter in `fireAllRules()`?

Comment: Would adding [Debug Event Listeners](https://docs.drools.org/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/#decision-examples-helloworld-ref_drools-examples) help determine the cause? ```ksession.addEventListener( new DebugAgendaEventListener() );``` and 
```ksession.addEventListener( new DebugRuleRuntimeEventListener() );```